# How can I fix the "Twilio::REST::RestError"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I followed the documentation here:
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/04/receive-and-reply-to-sms-in-rails.html

Now I have the following error:

```
Twilio::REST::RestError (Unable to create record: The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts//Messages.json was not found):
```

My messages controller code is:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController 
 skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
 # skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => "reply"

  def reply
    message_body = params["Body"]
    from_number = params["From"]
    init_twilio
    msg = @client.messages.create(
      from: Rails.application.secrets.twilio_number,
      to: from_number,
      body: "Hello! Your number is #{from_number}. This is a xxx 
Test Message."
    )

  end

  private

  def init_twilio
    account_sid = Rails.application.secrets.twilio_sid
    auth_token = Rails.application.secrets.twilio_auth_key
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hard to say with the level of detail given but usually there is an error in your secrets.yml file. Double check that our Twilio Keys are set properly.

Comment: That was it! Thank you... Always need to remember to set those properly in Heroku...

Comment: The best way to tell this is that the URL that failed looked like: `/2010-04-01/Accounts//Messages.json`. The double slash gives away that something is missing, in this case your Account SID which you've discovered wasn't set in secrets.yml.

Comment: @philnash I am using laravel and having the same issue. I receive a similar error `[HTTP 404] Unable to create record: The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/AC177c5f8f61d2f63596678f7f27e0c230/Messages.json was not found`
Please advise.

Comment: @AbdellahRamadan it looks like you have your Account SID set properly there and it is correct, so this is a different issue. How are you making this call? It might be best if you ask a new question and share your code.

Comment: @philnash thank you. I managed to have it working using vanilla PHP and Twilio PHP SDK than a Laravel package.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons for this could be that you secrets environment didn't pick up the changes in your environment. Run:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

To refresh the environment settings. And after that (**which is most probably the cause of this issue**), run this command to stop `spring` in order for the changes to be picked-up next time:

```
bin/spring stop
```